# clang-format causing compiled object files to change

Tags: c, gcc, clang-format

I'm working on a large codebase that needs to be formatted. With many hiccups, it's been formatted with a clean start to finish run of clang-format, and I've moved on to comparing the object files between the original build and the formatted build, as an attempt to check clang-format's work.

Much to my surprise, the compiled binaries are not the same. The only thing that I have fond so far is a difference in immediate offsets in a bunch of mov/add/store instructions:

```
file format elf64-littleaarch64
430c430
<      628:     52803e63        mov     w3, #0x1f3                      // #499
---
>      628:     52803ac3        mov     w3, #0x1d6                      // #470
```

The change appears to be consistent across each file (every mov/add in this file changes by 29 base 10), but not across files, another file I've checked has an offset of 10 base 10 between new and old binary.

The only thing I can think of is some sort of string that identifies the file has changed, but I don't see how that would happen, and it's not coming out in the diff of the disassembly.

What could be the cause of this change in offset? The only difference between the two source files is that one had clang-format run on it, with a near default set of rules

## Edit: a more detailed example:

```
 461c466
<     if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, "..")) {
---
>         if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))
465c470
<     1068:     91220001        add     x1, x0, #0x880
---
>     1068:     91224001        add     x1, x0, #0x890
473c478
<     1088:     91222001        add     x1, x0, #0x888
---
>     1088:     91226001        add     x1, x0, #0x898
```

And the relevant assembly from one of the files

```
if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))
105c:       f94037e0        ldr     x0, [sp, #104]
1060:       91004c02        add     x2, x0, #0x13
1064:       90000000        adrp    x0, 1000 <pciFindDevice+0x20>
1068:       91224001        add     x1, x0, #0x890
106c:       aa0203e0        mov     x0, x2
1070:       97ffff20        bl      cf0 <strcmp@plt>
1074:       7100001f        cmp     w0, #0x0
1078:       540006a0        b.eq    114c <pciFindDevice+0x16c>  // b.none
107c:       f94037e0        ldr     x0, [sp, #104]
1080:       91004c02        add     x2, x0, #0x13
1084:       90000000        adrp    x0, 1000 <pciFindDevice+0x20>
1088:       91226001        add     x1, x0, #0x898
108c:       aa0203e0        mov     x0, x2
```

Comment: Reading this particular file, there is no use of any of that. The movs and adds that are affected are all over the place, too. One of them was a series of adds to generate the arguments for a `strcpy`

Comment: @BrydonGibson: `__LINE__` is used in the `assert` macro, but could also be used in user macros to generate line relative offsets in array initializers (I have used that), or custom debugging information.

Comment: Can you identify the function with different code and try and compile the project with only one file reformatted, then with minimal reformatting.

Comment: Preprocess both old and new files, replace all whitespace with newlines, and compare.

Comment: Can you try and patch the source file, replacing `"."` with a longer unique string and verify you get the same difference, then use the method I posted in my answer to investigate where the shift occurs.

Comment: is `pciFindDevice` the function where the code fragment occurs? Can you post the full source code for this function? It seems the string constants are spliced in the code in the executable, so dumping the assembly for the function in both source trees should help pinpoint what is the first difference.

Comment: "Identify the function with different code" I don't understand what you mean here. There's thousands of files and they all have some sort of immediate addressing offset after formatting

Comment: Does the function `pciFindDevice` contain the line `if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))`?

Comment: @chqrlie yes, that's correct it does.

Comment: @BrydonGibson: the strings `"."` and `".."` are generated in the code segment at offset 0x20+0x890 relative to the start of this function, probably after the end of the function. Can you look at the assembly dump there to see if all string constants are identical? The string should be there, but shifted by 16 bytes, so you can try and identify where this shift occurs between the end of the code and the strings.

Comment: The function `pciFindDevice` starts at `0x114c-0x16c` = `0x1000-0x20`, hence the page whose memory address is loaded by the instruction `adrp    x0, 1000 <pciFindDevice+0x20>` is the second 4KB page in this module and the address you should look for the strings is a offset `0x1890` and before.

Comment: @chqrlie Bingo - the build directory appears compiled in, which is clearly different between the two (found with `diff <(strings old.o) <(strings new.o)`)

Comment: @BrydonGibson: this might explain the problem, although the build directory might appear in the `.o` files as debugging information, not necessarily a difference in the actual code and data in the executable image. Debugging information includes line numbers so will be very different in both object files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code uses `assert` macros, the expansion in `DEBUG` mode does generate code that depends on line numbering because the macro `__LINE__` gets expanded to a different value, which is passed to `fprintf` to produce the diagnostic with the file name and line number.

You can compare the code generated with assertions disabled.

You should also grep for `__LINE__` in the source code and include files to identify other potential uses of the line numbers in custom macros.

From the details in the question update, the differing data is the offset of the string constants for `"."` and `".."` used as arguments for `strcmp`. The final values for these offsets comes from the link loader after global object code optimisation by LLVM. Most or all string constants in this and other modules may be shifted in the executable, causing the offsets to change in many places in the executable code.

The code posted shows a difference only as a side effect of something else which may be in a different source file.

You can try and identify where this difference starts by loading both executable in a hex editor (eg: qemacs) and search for longer string constants to try and compare the binaries, scanning backwards to find the first difference explaining the shift. If this difference is a string constant that differs between the executables, you will have a good candidate to investigate further.

Comment: I'm confident after much digging that it's simply __LINE__ macros causing the issue. The question now would be how to globally disable __LINE__ in order to do the comparison?

Comment: @BrydonGibson: if you mean *how to globally disable `__LINE__` macros, it is usually impossible. but you could try and identify which macros use the `__LINE__` token by scanning through the source code and include files with `grep -rw __LINE__ .` and change these macros to use a fixed value instead*.

Comment: I am actually finding success with `-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined` and `-D__LINE__=\"10\"`, so now everything will come up as line 10

Comment: @BrydonGibson: interesting! not all compilers would allow this redefinition, but good for you if it works. The command line option should be `-D__LINE__=10` so the definition is an integer, not a string.

Comment: printf didn't complain about trying to use a string with `%d`. I think it's a safe guess that the shell consumes the quotes

Comment: @BrydonGibson: I'm afraid is it not a safe guess: the shell would consume the quotes if you wrote `-D__LINE__="10"`, but if you escape the quotes as `-D__LINE__=\"10\"` the definition should include the quotes, as if by `#define __LINE__ "10"`.  The compiler only complains about the type mismatch if it is configured to do so with `-Wall` etc.

Comment: Wow - I don't know what I was thinking yesterday, you're right. I was following another question that was doing a similar thing for `__TIME__` which does require a string literal. `-Wall` definitely should have told me I was being stupid though.